# Refresh Knockout ViewModel with Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a table that contains initial values. The user can filter data on the tables and the table should refresh. I cannot do this with knockout.

View:

```
<tbody id="tblMultiEdit" data-bind="foreach: UUTs">
   <tr>
     <td data-bind="text: SerialNumber"></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: (ReqDowngrade == 'Y' ? 1 : 0)" /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

View Model:

```
function ViewModel(UUTs) {

   var self = this;
   self.UUTs = UUTs;
};
```

Initial Binding:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Ajax Call to fetch new table values:

```
function search() {
            $("#btnSearch").click(
                function () {
                    $('#image').hide()
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "@Url.Action("search", "UUTs")",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data:
                            {
                                lab: $("#drpLab").val()
                            },
                        success: function (data) {

                            var viewModel = new ViewModel(data);    
                            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

                        }, error: function (ex) {
                            toastr.error('Failed to retrieve search results, please check your network connection.' + ex)
                        }
                    })
                }
                )
        }
```

Debugging I can see the JSON data on the success method of the Ajax call. What do I have to do to refresh the data?

Answer (score 0):

Declare UUTs as an observableArray first, then update it as you wish.
You should update the observable array that you are binding against, instead of re-declaring it.

```
function ViewModel(UUTs) {

   var self = this;
   self.UUTs = ko.observableArray(UUTs);
};
```

So in your ajax success callback you should do something like this:

```
    success: function (data) {
                                viewModel.UUTs(data); 
// assuming data is an array. otherwise some mapping my be needed
// reference to the same model, no new viewModel needed  
                            }
```

Comment: It worked but it was only giving me one value. Anyway I moved to another approach. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure "data" in the success callback contains an array? if you need more help about it let me know